# How can I stop my action bar from moving in django admin?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, django-suit

I am currently using django admin with suit as the interface. My problem is that sometimes the aciton bar is on the top and sometimes its on the bottom and I don;t know why. How can I restrict it to one position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which version you're using, but ModelAdmin probably [has a setting that will help you](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-options).

Try something like this in admin.py:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....
    actions_on_bottom = True
    actions_on_top = False
```